# How to get DATA from unnamed JSON Object array

Tags: javascript, json

I used fetch method to get data from JSON into Object array and now I want to get only one value from object, but my array doesn't have name.

JS:

```
async function s_data() {
  let r = await fetch("terms.json");
  let d = await r.json();
  return d;
}
```

Array looks like

```
0: Object { TERM: "x", PRIORITY: "1" }
​​
1: Object { TERM: "y", PRIORITY: "0" }
​​
2: Object { TERM: "z", PRIORITY: "0" }
​​
```

And i want to paste only terms into Array.

Comment: What do you mean "the array doesn't have a name"? It's `d` in your example.

Comment: @Quentin I dont know how to call it I want to use map() method, if is there any other way, just tell me.

Comment: `const converted = d.map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
async function s_data() {
  let r = await fetch("terms.json");
  let d = await r.json();
  let terms = d.map(item => item.TERM);
  return terms;
}
```

Or:

```
async function s_data() {
  let r = await fetch("terms.json");
  let d = await r.json();
  let terms = d.reduce((acc, item) => {acc.push(item.TERM); return acc}, []);
  return terms;
}
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Thanks it works. Can i have one more question? i got Event and I want to filter this array inside it. I call s_data().filter(x => x.includes(DATA_SPACE)); and I'm getting TypeError: s_data(...).filter is not a function

Comment: @mckvak Looks like you need to add "await" keyword: let results = await s_data(); results.filter(x => x.includes(DATA_SPACE));